Golang ABI coding Why does coding overflow occur?
The incoming data is the same, why does python output: ：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
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64
from web3 import Web3

def create_op_signature(
        valid_until: int,
        valid_after: int,
        merkle_root: bytes,
        merkle_proof: list,
        r_signature: bytes,
    ):
    S_S = '0x1965cd0Bf68Db7D007613E79d8386d48B9061ea6'

    w3 = Web3()

    encoded_data = w3.codec.encode(
        ["uint48", "uint48", "bytes32", "bytes32[]", "bytes"],
        [valid_until, valid_after, merkle_root, merkle_proof, r_signature]
    )

    final_encoded_data = w3.codec.encode(
        ["bytes", "address"],
        [encoded_data, S_S]
    )

    return final_encoded_data.hex()

# TestData
valid_until = 1717313849
valid_after = 1717312649
merkle_root = bytes.fromhex('c44803d668d227725b5515b3370184e36a7d2ca459e4414f26881a7e06763917')
merkle_proof = [bytes.fromhex('22441ff34f6681f8b06ad9eca5a0d45223822ce945d5e53e18a7d1caf53969bd')]
r_signature = bytes.fromhex('250218ec12ab58eeae7ff078f2270c6de9e1ae5cb65d62de2733b4ad477b3fd027e5898c57f1d660f766e4b97b78106855f200e4ebf980d336db1a59cdc11c5d1b')

print(merkle_root.hex())
print(r_signature.hex())
signature = create_op_signature(valid_until, valid_after, merkle_root, merkle_proof, r_signature)
print(signature)

golang output：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
func createOpSignature(validUntil, validAfter int64, merkleRoot, merkleProof, rSignature []byte) string {
    // S_S address
    SS := ethcommon.HexToAddress("0x1965cd0Bf68Db7D007613E79d8386d48B9061ea6")

    log.Println(SS)

    encodeABI := `[{"name":"encode","type":"function","inputs":[{"type":"uint48"},{"type":"uint48"},{"type":"bytes32"},{"type":"bytes32[]"},{"type":"bytes"}],"outputs":[{"type":"bytes"}]},{"name":"encodeWithAddress","type":"function","inputs":[{"type":"bytes"},{"type":"address"}],"outputs":[{"type":"bytes"}]}]`
    ABI, err := abi.JSON(bytes.NewReader([]byte(encodeABI)))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to parse ABI: %v", err)
    }


    validUntilBig := new(big.Int).SetUint64(uint64(validUntil) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF)
    validAfterBig := new(big.Int).SetUint64(uint64(validAfter) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF)

    var merkleRootFixed [32]byte
    copy(merkleRootFixed[:], merkleRoot)

    log.Printf("merkleRootFixed:%x", merkleRootFixed)

    var merkleProofFixed [][32]byte
    for i := 0; i < len(merkleProof); i += 32 {
        var proof [32]byte
        copy(proof[:], merkleProof[i:i+32])
        merkleProofFixed = append(merkleProofFixed, proof)
    }

    log.Printf("merkleProofFixed:%x", merkleProofFixed)

    encodedParams, err := ABI.Pack("encode", validUntilBig, validAfterBig, merkleRootFixed, merkleProofFixed, rSignature)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to encode data: %v", err)
    }


    finalEncodedData, err := ABI.Pack("encodeWithAddress", encodedParams, SS)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to encode final data: %v", err)
    }

    log.Println("ABI DATA:", validUntilBig, validAfterBig, merkleRootFixed, merkleProofFixed, rSignature, hex.EncodeToString(finalEncodedData))
    log.Println("string(rSignature)", hex.EncodeToString(rSignature))
    return "0x" + hex.EncodeToString(finalEncodedData)
}


The encoding content output by python is available, but not by golang. Is it a data type conversion error? Doesn't go have a library as convenient as python?
The encoding content output by python is available, but not by golang. Is it a data type conversion error? Doesn't go have a library as convenient as python?
